# Initialisation of traits.Tuple value in a traits.Tuple object

Tags: python, python-3.x, traits

```
>>> import traits.api as traits
>>> class Foo(traits.HasTraits):
...  eTest = traits.Tuple((0.0001, 60, traits.Tuple(traits.Bool(False), traits.Bool(True))))
... 
>>> a=Foo()
>>> a.eTest
(0.0001, 60, <traits.trait_types.Tuple object at 0x7fa825fceac8>)
>>> a.eTest=(0.0001, 60, (False, True))
>>> a.eTest
(0.0001, 60, (False, True))
```

How initialise values of a.eTest to (0.0001, 60, (False, True)) concomitantly to the instantiation of a. ? Currently I need to define a.eTest=(0.0001, 60, (False, True)) after the instantiation of a.

Answer (score 0):

The devil is in the details ...

```
>>> class Foo(traits.HasTraits):
...  eTest = traits.Tuple(0.0001, 60, traits.Tuple(traits.Bool(False), traits.Bool(True)))
... 
>>> a=Foo()
>>> a.eTest
(0.0001, 60, (False, True))
```

After trying a lot of things, I noticed that by not specifying a tuple as the first argument, I obtains the wanted result ! I confess that I do not exactly understand all in the traits module. [For example it seems that by not specifying a tuple as the first argument, the default values would be the default values for the corresponding trait types !!!](http://docs.enthought.com/traits/_modules/traits/trait_types.html#BaseTuple)